# how to call columns from database and format it with HTML code

Tags: php, html, css

Actually I am beginner programmer in HTML, CSS and PHP. I have simple website for add and register in courses. The user should be add course into website and the courses should be posted on the site.so users can browse and register.

Actually my problem is how to call the course name from database and how to format it with HTML code as I want.

This is the page of courses which is content the list of available courses in website ( please note it is only HTML code, I do that to see how the page will be )

**Screenshot of page:**

[image: screenshot of page]

So as you see, the first page include many this HTML code to add course list into website with the following code:

```
<div class="card card-1">
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1/project2/course details/course1.php">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/coursepic.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:101% "></a>      <div class="container">
    <h4 class="textstyle"><b>Operating System</b> </h4>
    <p class="textstyle">Free Course</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i want do with PHP?

I want to write a PHP code to replace the P and h4 with the course name, cost of courses from my database for each available course.

Please note: the pic for each course it will be from my pc, no need to call the pic from database.

I tried to write PHP code like below:

```
        <div>

    <div class="card card-1">
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1/project2/course details/course1.php">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/coursepic.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:101% "></a>      <div class="container">     

    <?php 

     include_once("db.php");
    $result = mysqli_query(OpenCon(), "SELECT Course_Name,cost FROM `course`");
    //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
    echo "<p>".$res['Course_Name']."</p>";   
    echo "<p>".$res['cost']."</p>";   

    }

    ?>

</div>
</div>




        </div>
```

**This is my result:**

[image: screenshot of page]

It's okay but I want the style to be like the first screenshot. each course should have picture.

After that when the user click on course name. I want move to another page which is content the course details ( for the same course that user clicked ) also it's called for my database

like this:

[image: screenshot of page]

I hope any one help my to solve this problem only, I should solve this problem within 2 days only. and sorry if my explanation is bad.

Thanks in advance for everyone.

Comment: The while() in your PHP will create a loop (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).  This means that all of the information from your database will go through the code you have in the loop.  So you will want to figure out a way to put your HTML inside of the loop so that with each iteration a new card is added.

Comment: great, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a PHP loop.....

So, this

```
<div class="card card-1">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1/project2/course details/course1.php">
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/coursepic.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:101% ">
    </a>     
    <div class="container">
        <h4 class="textstyle"><b>Operating System</b> </h4>
        <p class="textstyle">Free Course</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Becomes (after cleaning up the code a bit - I think you didn't mean to use two `<p>` in there, but I left them so you can see it.  Note that using different lines for the segments makes it a lot easier to see what you have.)

```
include_once("db.php");
$result = mysqli_query(OpenCon(), "SELECT Course_Name,cost FROM `course`");
$count = 0;
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
    $count ++;    
    // NOTE: Here is the LOOP! - not outside the query, but INSIDE it
    // First you 'jump out' of PHP, going back to HTML
    ?> <!-- now you are in HTML (when you need PHP again, you 'jump in' and 'jump out' as needed - see the code below....) -->
    <div class="card card-<?php echo $count;?>">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/project2/course details/course<?php echo $count;?>.php">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/coursepic.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:101% ">
        </a>     
        <div class="container">
            <h4 class="textstyle">
                <b><p><?php echo $res['Course_Name'];?></p></b> 
            </h4>
            <p class="textstyle">
                <p><?php echo $res['cost'];?></p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php // we are in PHP again....  
}
```

That should do what you asked for - though I would go a step (well, more than one...) further and make as much of this dynamic as you can.

For this I will presume that:

1. your database table has a column called 'id' (if it doesn't, you should have) and it relates to the course number (you could make a course number column if they don't match up, but I'm keeping it simple)
2. you have all your pictures labeled 'coursepicX' where the X is the course number.

We'll use 'coursepic' as a default in case there isn't a picture yet...

Now, the code is more dynamic!

```
include_once("db.php");
$result = mysqli_query(OpenCon(), "SELECT id,Course_Name,cost FROM `course`");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
    // NOTE: Here is the LOOP! - not outside the query, but INSIDE it
    // First you 'jump out' of PHP, going back to HTML
    ?> <!-- now you are in HTML (when you need PHP again, you 'jump in' and 'jump out' as needed - see the code below....) -->
    <div class="card card-<?php echo $res['id']?>">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/project2/course details/course<?php echo $res['id']?>.php">
            <?php 
            $pic = "http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/coursepic.jpg";
            if(file_exists("http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/course" . $res['id'] . ".jpg") {
                $pic = "http://127.0.0.1/project2/icons/course" . $res['id'] . ".jpg";
            }
            <img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:101% ">
        </a>     
        <div class="container">
            <h4 class="textstyle">
                <b><p><?php echo $res['Course_Name'];?></p></b> 
            </h4>
            <p class="textstyle">
                <p><?php echo $res['cost'];?></p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php // we are in PHP again....  
}
```

Note that this is the basic 'shopping cart' sort of program - you will likely use it many (many) times in your career.

Happy Coding!